# How to round a vector of values so that the sum of the rounded values will always add up to a certain number (here 100)

Tags: r

Let's assume I have the following vector of values:

```
input <- c(5.170669324, 8.69978618, 8.386448608, 9.765707038, 9.725934478, 6.37837945, 1.770207313, 4.64951078, 7.69234579, 8.060673651, 9.656558295, 9.933008843, 7.141666039, 2.969104213)
```

I now want to round these values to zero digits, which would give me:

```
round(input, 0)

[1]  5  9  8 10 10  6  2  5  8  8 10 10  7  3
```

Problem is, these numbers now add up to 101, but I need to find a rounding that will give me exactly 100.

My thought was that I could calculate the difference of the original values to the rounded values and then sequentially start with the value that would closest to x.5 and then switch its direction, i.e. in my case I have 101 as a sum, I need to go down to 100, so I will change the value closest to and higher than .5 (here, the 4.64...) to the lower number, so this number wouldn't be rounded to 5, but isntead to 4. If the sum would have been 99, I would do it the other way around.

Does that sound like a reasonable approach or is there a mathematically more appropriate method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this algorithm does what you need.

If the sum of the rounded values is more than the target, it rounds down the most appropriate number (the one which was furthest from the integer to which it was rounded up). It repeats this process if required until the target is reached. If the sum of the rounded values is smaller than the target, it will round up the most appropriate numbers until the target is reached:

```r
round_to_target <- function(x, target = round(sum(x))) {

  while(sum(round(x)) - target > 0) {
    i <- which.min(ifelse(x %% 1 < 0.5, 1, x %% 1))
    x[i] <- x[i] - 1
  }
  while(sum(round(x)) - target < 0) {
    i <- which.max(ifelse(x %% 1 > 0.5, 0, x %% 1))
    x[i] <- x[i] + 1
  }
  round(x)
}
```

Testing on your example, we have

```r
round_to_target(input)
#> [1]  5  9  8 10 10  6  2  4  8  8 10 10  7  3

sum(round_to_target(input))
#> [1] 100
```

And to show it is a general solution, let's generate some random numbers that add up to 200:

```r
set.seed(1)

x <- diff(sort(c(0, runif(14, 0, 200), 200)))

x
#>  [1] 12.3572541 22.9540964  5.0250357  0.8585288 11.9068176 21.3230473
#>  [7]  2.3959637 37.7499290 11.2521361  6.3367497  5.2450108 42.2733677
#> [13]  1.9636210  7.2934957 11.0649463
```

Note that summing the rounded values gives us less than 200:

```r
sum(round(x))
#> [1] 198
```

But if we use `round_to_target`, we get

```r
round_to_target(x)
#>  [1] 12 23  5  1 12 21  4 38 11  6  5 42  2  7 11

sum(round_to_target(x))
#> [1] 200
```

Comment: Yes, I think this does it. Will test tomorrow. I think this can also be simplified without a while loop. E.g. if the sum is 97 or 103, we can simply divide the input vector by that number * 100. And after that I believe it‘s guaranteed that changing the ONE number that is closest to 0.5 would lead to the sum being 100.

Comment: @deschen that may work, though the while loop isn't a big deal here, as it will typically need 0 or 1 iterations. It almost never needs more than 3 iterations for a vector of this size.

Comment: I think it will at max need 0.5*length(x) iterations.

Comment: @deschen yes, in theory, but that's incredibly unlikely for anything but the shortest input vectors, and even then it's only going to be a couple of iterations.

Comment: Yep. Agree. And also noticed that my idea above won‘t work. E.g. with an input vector of `c(rep(9.5,9), 14.5)` it will not work.

Comment: Works nicely. Had to do some adjustment in case the numbers are e.g. proportions as 0.05 and so on, but that was not so difficult.

Comment: `i <- which.min(ifelse(x %% 1 < 0.5, NA, x %% 1))` would work and be slightly faster

Comment: @deschen Can you show your implementation?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I did this as part of my former occupation, so I don‘t have access to that piece of code anymore.